# Voltage Shift 0-5V to 0- (-300mV)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, level-shifting

Ive been hurting my brain a lot on this one and reading up on opamps, clamps, and level shifters, but still can't figure it out.

I need to take a 0v to 5v signal (TTL) and convert it to 0v to (negative) 300mV.

So far, I only could find this circuit which shifts this in reverse and meant for AC:
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/4/4836.html

Id be super grateful for any help! :)

Edit: The reason I was adding the 2nd opamp was I wanted to use it as a simple NOT gate, since I have it to spare.  Any tips how to do that with the split supply?

Comment: Use an opamp with a gain of -0.0600.  You will need a negative rail if you want a negative voltage.

Comment: That’s an unusual requirement. Can you explain a bit more what it is for?

Comment: Refer to the old Texas Instruments "TTL Data Book" for the details on TTL levels.

Comment: Your question is missing important information.  1.  What power supply voltages are available for this?  2.  What is the longest possible time the signal will be in the -300 mV state?  3.  Which input level (0 V or +5 V) is being translated to -300 mV?

Comment: you can invert to -5 then scale down with R's . How much current? Use a suitable V+/V- supply.

Comment: What speed do you need? With 5V in do you want 0V or -0.3V out?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two op-amps. Your circuit has a double inversion so it will give +300mV out for 5V in, not -300mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDsST7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @user1850479, I needed that nudge to know I was going in the right direction.  It helped me have the confidence to keep going (which I often lack and self-doubt) and make this :D

edit: removed 2nd opamp (thanks @Spehro Pefhany)

Simulated the the opamp in Circuit Lab and it worked perfectly.  Ran out of my free trial before simulating the opamp beginning inverter, lol, but I think it should work fine.
Really happy with this!
[image]